# MOTD shows output from previous session?

Tags: linux, ssh, ubuntu-14.04

I have a custom MOTD that I see every time I login with ssh.
The MOTD shows various stats and system info.

I recently noticed the info is incorrect. Actually it is correct, just not for the current session. I've tested this by adding `date` to MOTD, and it always shows the last time I login.

How can I make it execute the MOTD script every time I login?

Thanks.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: I just redressed it. Actually, it made no sense to me either.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is the default behavior, and in order to change this an edit is required to `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
 session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic noupdate
```

Once I removed `noupdate` it solved my issue.